# Pass mysql query containing mysql function to PHP mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have this code

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GetNextID` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `GetNextID`() RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE NextID INT;
SELECT MAX(articleID) + 5 INTO NextID FROM table_article;
RETURN NextID;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO table_article ( articleID, articleAlias ) VALUES ( GetNextID(), 'TEST' );
```

executed OK in phpMyAdmin, but it fails when i pass this query to mysql_query PHP function/
Me guess this is because of the function and **semi-colons**. What do i do?

Comment: It would help to post your code and the error you're getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DELIMITER` is not a `MySQL` keyword: it is a reserved word parsed by clients (like `mysql`, `phpMyAdmin` etc.) which allows splitting the queries.

You should split it manually and submit the three queries:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GetNextID`
```

,

```
CREATE FUNCTION `GetNextID`() RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE NextID INT;
SELECT MAX(articleID) + 5 INTO NextID FROM table_article;
RETURN NextID;
END
```

and

```
INSERT INTO table_article ( articleID, articleAlias ) VALUES ( GetNextID(), 'TEST' )
```

in three separate calls to the database.

Comment: yeah, i was going to, but stackoverflow told me to wait for 3 minutes, though ;) here you go...

Answer (score 0):

you have DECLARE NextID INT; and RETURN NextID; and another line with ; inside the DELIMITER $$ deceleration.

my advice is stop using $$ as a delimiter

Comment: what to use instead? can you rewrite the code the right way, pls? =]